# How to get output into dictionary format from given data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a field where value is as below

```
b = [
        {
            "category": "Engineer",
            "name": "Anthony Test",
            "id": 219
        },
        {
            "category": "Engineer",
            "name": "Pete Junior",
            "id": 220
        }
    ]
```

I would like to get the result in below format where I want to eliminate category and create a dictionary with id and name

```
result = {'219': 'Anthony Test', '220': 'Pete Junior'}
```

Comment: Any good tutorial should have covered everything you need to solve this yourself. SO is not the place for this.

Comment: original data is not in JSON format

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary comprehension

```
{i['id']: i['name'] for i in b}
```